# How to come out of method execution based on a condition in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I'm a Java developer and new to protractor. I'm trying to iterate through a dynamic web table in a web page and trying to find out a particular user name and open his profile. Once I open his profile, I want my test method to stop execution and return. But the return statement doesn't work and the for loop still runs. Could anyone please help me with this? Below is my method.

```
searchUser() {
// Iterate through the user listing table 
 browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal')).then(function (table) {
  table.findElement(by.tagName('tbody')).then(function (tbody) {
    tbody.findElements(by.tagName('tr')).then(function (rows) {
       for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].findElements(by.tagName('td')).then(function (cols) {
          cols[1].getText().then(function (user) {
            if (user == "ADAM SMITH") {
              // found user, open his profile
             cols[1].click();
             return;

            }
          });

        });
      }
      // user not found in the current page. Click on next page and continue search
      element(by.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div/app-users-profile/users-listing/form/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button")).click();
      browser.sleep(3000);
      var currentPage = new LoginPage();
      currentPage.searchUser(); 

        });
    });
  });
```

}

Comment: Your current code is not high efficient. Please show the HTML of your table, maybe we can give an efficient solution.

Comment: My advice is try to decompose your huge method to several smaller methods. Also in some place you handle promises and in some places not.

Answer (score 0):

I try to make as less differences as I can.

```
async function searchUser () {
  let result = false;
  while (!result) {
    const table = browser.$('.slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal');
    const tbody = table.$('tbody');
    const rows = tbody.$$('tr');
    await rows.map(async (row) => {
      const column = row.findElements(by.tagName('td')).get(1);
      const name = await column.getText();
      if (name === 'ADAM SMITH') {
        await column.click();
        result = true;
      }
    });
    if (!result) {
      await element(by.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div/app-users-profile/users-listing/form/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button")).click();
      await browser.sleep(3000);
      const currentPage = new LoginPage();
      await currentPage.searchUser();
    }
  }
}
```